# mitmproxy 5.1.1 always crashed

Tags: django, mitmproxy

I encountered mitmproxy crash issue with Windows 10 64-bit build 19041.207
Following are my crash logs

```
Mitmproxy: 5.1.1 build pypi_0 from pypi
Python: 3.7.6 from conda-forge
OpenSSL: 1.1.1g build he774522_0 from conda-forge
pyopenssl: 19.1.0 build py_1 from conda-forge
cryptography: 2.9.2 build pypi_0 from pypi
==================
D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\python.exe D:/Dev/Anaconda3/envs/WXC_prj/src/main.py
2020-04-23 22:40:16.216 | INFO | web_server::32 - Gevent server mode
2020-04-23 22:40:19.039 | INFO | web_server::32 - Gevent server mode
`Proxy server listening at http://*:8080
192.168.1.17:58307: clientconnect
192.168.1.17:58309: clientconnect
192.168.1.17:58307: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\server.py", line 121, in handle root_layer()  
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\modes\http_proxy.py", line 9, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 285, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http1.py", line 83, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 190, in call if not self._process_flow(flow):
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 262, in _process_flow return self.handle_regular_connect(f)
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 208, in handle_regular_connect layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 278, in call self._establish_tls_with_client_and_server()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 358, in _establish_tls_with_client_and_server self._establish_tls_with_server()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 448, in _establish_tls_with_server **args
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\connections.py", line 292, in establish_tls self.convert_to_tls(cert=client_cert, sni=sni, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\net\tcp.py", line 386, in convert_to_tls **sslctx_kwargs
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\net\tls.py", line 285, in create_client_context param = SSL._lib.SSL_CTX_get0_param(context._context)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_get0_param'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\server.py", line 121, in handle root_layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\modes\http_proxy.py", line 9, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 285, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http1.py", line 83, in call layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 190, in call if not self._process_flow(flow):
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 262, in _process_flow return self.handle_regular_connect(f)
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\http.py", line 208, in handle_regular_connect layer()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 278, in call self._establish_tls_with_client_and_server()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 358, in _establish_tls_with_client_and_server self._establish_tls_with_server()
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\proxy\protocol\tls.py", line 448, in _establish_tls_with_server **args
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\connections.py", line 292, in establish_tls self.convert_to_tls(cert=client_cert, sni=sni, **kwargs)
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\net\tcp.py", line 386, in convert_to_tls **sslctx_kwargs
File "D:\Dev\Anaconda3\envs\WXC_prj\lib\site-packages\mitmproxy\net\tls.py", line 285, in create_client_context param = SSL._lib.SSL_CTX_get0_param(context._context)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'SSL_CTX_get0_param'`

mitmproxy has crashed!
Please lodge a bug report at: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy
```

Comment: The function `SSL_CTX_get0_param` that is mentioned in the error log was introduced in OpenSSL 1.0.2. Hence you should check if your OpenSSL version is at least 1.0.2.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you are using an outdated version of the [cryptography library](https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/).